# Why the Express POST no response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

server.js (listen 5000 port)

```
import express from "express";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
const app = express();
app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
```

userRoutes.js

```
import express from "express";
import { authUser } from "../controllers/userController.js";
const router = express.Router();
router.route("/login").post(authUser);
export default router;
```

userController.js

```
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
export const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  res.send(email);
});
```

[image: Always sending, no results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the method in Postman to POST

Comment: It's not ‘sending request’ now, but the rep.body doesn't have any value...

Comment: it totally works now, I also need to change 'text' to 'json' on postman.